# bluetooth and wired headphones at the same time

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

When travelling, sometimes my girlfriend and I like to watch tv shows or movies together on my phone.

I have bluetooth headphones and she has wired.  Only one set of headphones can get the audio at the moment.

Does anyone know of a way to get android to put the audio out on both the 3.5 jack and the bluetooth headphones at the same time?